# Visual Studio 2017 hangs on Start Up

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional. It was working fine the first day just recently its hangs up has I opened visual studio 2017.

Note: I am running it on admin mode

Also once before this issue began to occur , an error occurred that visual studio is blocked by one of the programs which was strange.

I am using windows 10

Comment: Not much to go on.

Comment: need to post whole error

Comment: Sadly depending on the version of VS2017 you installed, it could have some 'bugs'  I will give MS credit with VS2017 as they seem to be releasing updates for it very quickly.  This may be 'annoying' but try uninstalling VS2017 then download and re-install it fresh.

Comment: I did a repair and it seems to be working fine till now

Comment: It occurs again and again even after repairing or reinstalling for me

Comment: try downloading again perhaps

Comment: I had few issues as well. After numerous trial and error methods , i removed Avast it worked well. Not sure if these will be news to you however